# Need Schema for createDataFrame for type map(key,struct())

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6.2 . Can someone provide me schema for `createDataFrame(rdd,schema)`.

I am not able to define schema for map types below.

```
DF.printSchema()
 |-- PRODUCT_IMAGE_MAP: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- image_path: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- image_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- image_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SKU_ID_SITE_MAP: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- SKU_ID_SITEID_LIST: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Your queestion is unclear. Please add more details. A dataframe is already there, why do you want a Schema? What kind of schema do you want to define for a MapType column? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to load this DF to cassandra. But above DF column datatypes and different from cassandra types. So i want to create a schema manually to match with cassandra types.

Comment: here's how you should create map schema for SKU_ID_SITE_MAP  `StructField("SKU_ID_SITE_MAP", DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, StringType), true)` do the same for others as well